# Erro de rede React Native upload image

Tags: php, javascript, react-native, upload, image

Estou com um problema ao fazer o upload de imagens usando o React Native, quando eu seleciono a imagem o aplicativo retorna um erro de rede.

**Meu código:**

```
  state = {
avatarSource: null,
isUploading: false
```

}

```
  selectImage = async () => {
    ImagePicker.showImagePicker({ title: 'Selecionar Foto',
    noData: true,
    mediaType: 'photo',
    takePhotoButtonTitle: 'Tirar foto',
    chooseFromLibraryButtonTitle: 'Escolher da Galeria' },
    (response) => {


  if (response.didCancel) {
    Alert.alert('Error','User cancelled image picker');
  } else if (response.error) {
    Alert.alert('Error','ImagePicker Error: ');
  } else if (response.customButton) {
    Alert.alert('Error','User tapped custom button: ');
  } else {
    this.uploadImage(response.uri);
  }
});
```

}

```
  uploadImage = async (image_uri) => {
    this.setState({ isUploading: true });
    let base_url = 'http://192.168.0.101:80/config/upload.php/';
    let uploadData = new FormData();
    uploadData.append('submit', 'ok');
    uploadData.append('file', { type: 'image/jpg', uri: image_uri, name: 'uploadimgtmp.jpg' });
    fetch(base_url, {
      method: 'post',
      body: uploadData
    }).then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status) {
          this.setState({ isUploading: false, avatarSource: base_url + response.image });
        } else {
          this.setState({ isUploading: false });
          Alert.alert('error', response.message);
        }
      }).catch(() => {
        this.setState({ isUploading: false });
        Alert.alert('Error', 'Erro na rede');
      })
  }

  render() {
const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.txtbg}>
      <Text style={styles.headertxt}>Quase lá!</Text>
    </View>
    <Text style={styles.headertxt2}>ADICIONAR  FOTO  DE  PERFIL</Text>
    {this.state.avatarSource && <Image style={{ borderWidth: 2, borderColor: '#fff', width: 170, height: 170, resizeMode: 'cover', borderRadius: 120 }} source={{ uri: this.state.avatarSource }} />}
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.selectImage} style={styles.loginFoto}>
      <Text style={styles.loginText}>ESCOLHER FOTO</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    {this.state.isUploading && <ActivityIndicator size="small" color="#fff" />}
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.loginBtn}>
      <Text style={styles.loginText}>CONTINUAR  <Icon name="angle-right" size={16} /><Icon name="angle-right" size={16} /></Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity>
      <Text style={styles.loginText2}>PULAR</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
);
```

}

Esse é o código React Native, ele se comunica com um servidor **PHP**, que no momento está rodando no **LOCALHOST**.

O código **PHP** é o seguinte:

```
$data = array('status'=> false);

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $target_file = basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
    $file_type = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $is_image = getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

if ($is_image !== false) {
    $data['image'] = tine() . '.' . $file_type;
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $data['image'])) {
        $data['status'] = true;
    }else{
    $data['message'] = 'Falha ao carregar foto';
    }
}else{
    $data['message'] = 'Arquivo invalido!';
}
```

}

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin *');
header('Content-type:application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

Quando eu seleciono a imagem ele cai logo no erro de rede:

```
 .catch(() => {
        this.setState({ isUploading: false });
        Alert.alert('Error', 'Erro na rede');
      })
```

Eu estou rodando a aplicação no meu próprio Smartphone que se comunica com minha maquina.
Creio que o problema realmente seja no código , afinal eu tenho outros formulários que se comunicam bem com o servidor e meu servidor local (**WAMPSERVER**) está configurado para permitir uploads independente do tamanho!

**Versões utilizadas:**

```
  SDKs:
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 27, 28
      Build Tools: 27.0.3, 28.0.3
  npmPackages:
    react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0
    react-native: 0.61.5 => 0.61.5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pela descrição do seu erro, o problema pode estar no seu backend, pode ter ocorrido algum problema com a resposta, por isso ele caiu no "catch". Uma forma de tentar identificar o problema é imprimir no console a mensagem de erro, para isso, teria que fazer o seguinte ajuste na função de enviar imagem

```
 uploadImage = async (image_uri) => {
    this.setState({ isUploading: true });
    let base_url = 'http://192.168.0.101:80/config/upload.php/';
    let uploadData = new FormData();
    uploadData.append('submit', 'ok');
    uploadData.append('file', { type: 'image/jpg', uri: image_uri, name: 'uploadimgtmp.jpg' });

    console.log(uploadData); //Para conferir os dados do formulario

    fetch(base_url, {
      method: 'post',
      body: uploadData
    }).then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status) {
          this.setState({ isUploading: false, avatarSource: base_url + response.image });
        } else {
          this.setState({ isUploading: false });
          Alert.alert('error', response.message);
        }
      }) .catch(error => {
        console.log("Erro", error); //Para ver o erro que foi recebido
        this.setState({ isUploading: false });
        Alert.alert('Error', 'Erro na rede');
      });
  }
```

Eu recomendo você testar o upload de imagem direto para o seu backend usando o Postman. Aqui tem um tutorial explicando como fazer isso:

https://www.roytuts.com/how-to-call-file-upload-rest-api-using-postman/